# Set WPF TabControl to show the same Content for every tab

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I'd like to use a TabControl where each tab shows the same view just with different parameters. Therefore I do not want to create a new content control for each tab but reuse the same control for all tabs (binding some properties of it to the `SelectedItem` property of the `TabControl`)

I tried to my contained control as resource and set the `Content` property of the tab items to it, but this resulted in an exception, because the same element cannot appear as content in to different parents.

Any ideas?

Comment: One possibility is to create a TabControl only with tabs, no content. And create a separate control positioned under the tab control, with your content, and change the parameters based on the selected tab

Comment: I thought of that solution too, but you get a different visual style since the tab control also draws a border around it's content.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<TabControl>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               your view
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's even less writing than the solution I found myself!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this question

- [TabControl's TabItems sharing same content... Do Not Want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485789/tabcontrols-tabitems-sharing-same-content-do-not-want)

(even if the poster wanted specifically the opposite behaviour :) ...)