# Turn off WPF TabControl ContentTemplate For Some Tabs

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, contenttemplate

I hope this is an easy question. (Been coding for years, but limited WPF experience.) I have a simple tab control.

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl">
```

That contains three tabs:

```
<TabItem Name ="View" Header="View">
   stuff here to view data
</TabItem>

<TabItem Name ="Add" Header="Add">
   a form to add data
</TabItem>

<TabItem Name ="Edit" Header="Edit">
   the same form to edit data
</TabItem>
```

Since I want Add/Edit to share the same controls I created a ContentTemplate per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350528/set-wpf-tabcontrol-to-show-the-same-content-for-every-tab) answer.

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      stuff in here
   </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

However, ALL my tabs share the DataTemplate. How to I hide/exclude the View tab from sharing these controls?

Comment: I think your two choices are going to be: 1.  Put controls that you want every tab to have in the template, 2.  Put controls that are specific to one or more tabs (but not others) in the tabs you want them to be in.

Comment: You also might try adjusting the Visible or Collapsed property of the controls based on which tab you're on.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I like that idea.

Comment: are you using MVVM or code behind?

Comment: Code behind. It's a very simple app.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you have a distinct view model type for each type of data that you want to display in an `ItemsControl`. Each of these view models would be displayed using a `DataTemplate` that defines their appearance, e.g.:

- The *View* tab would have a view model of type `ViewData`
- The *Add* and *Edit* tabs would have a view model of type `ItemData`

You would create data templates for each of these view model or data types for your `TabControl`.

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
   <TabControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewData}">
         <!--...your "View" tab controls.-->
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemData}">
         <!--...your "Add" and "Edit" tab controls.-->
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

By only specifying a `DataType` the templates will automatically be applied to the corresponding item types in `ItemsSource`. This also works, if you add `TabItems` manually and set the data items as content, e.g.:

```
<TabItem Name ="View" Header="View">
   <MyTreeFolder:ViewData/>
</TabItem>
```

As an alternative to the implicit data templates, you can create a custom [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netcore-3.1) and override `SelectTemplate`. This way, you can select data templates not only depending on the data type, but also individual properties, fields, methods or attributes, whatever you need.

```
public class TabControlDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      if (item == null || !(container is FrameworkElement frameworkElement))
         return null;

      if (item is ViewData)
         return (DataTemplate)frameworkElement.FindResource("ViewDataTemplate");

      if (item is ItemData)
         return (DataTemplate)frameworkElement.FindResource("ItemDataTemplate");

      return null;
   }
}
```

In XAML, you would create data templates with a key and add the data template selector.

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl">
   <TabControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="ViewDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:ViewData}">
         <!--...your "View" tab controls.-->
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:ItemData}">
         <!--...your "Add" and "Edit" tab controls.-->
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.Resources>
   <TabControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
      <local:TabControlDataTemplateSelector/>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
</TabControl>
```

Again this works both for an `ItemsSource` and manually added data items in a `TabItem`.